# XAML Namespace Across a Network

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, designer, xml-namespaces

I have an issue with the xaml not being able to find the declared namespace until runtime. So when I'm not debugging the designer doesn't allow me to access the controls and displays the error:

> Error 1   Unable to load the metadata for assembly 'IConverterExample2'. This assembly may have been downloaded from the web.  See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545.  The following error was encountered during load: Could not load file or assembly 'IConverterExample2' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported.

However when I start debugging the program works as expected. I'm running this program off a network drive. If I copy the project to the desktop it works without a problem. Do I need to be more specific with my namespace decleration accross a network? the xaml:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IConverterExample2.ConverterSample"

...

<Grid.Resources>
<local:NumConverter x:Key="objNumConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My guess is file access.  You may have execute on the share which is good for the .exe but the .exe needs read access to other files.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment - made me think about where everything was being built etc. I changed the Properties/Compile/Build output path to a local location (for the debug configuration). So now the project resides on the network but builds locally - the XAML code can now see the resource!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is file access. You may have execute on the share which is good for the .exe but the .exe needs read access to other files.